# Why should we define foreign keys as primary keys in pivot table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, many-to-many, pivot-table, primary-key

Today I faced something, Someone defined foreign keys as primary keys in Pivot Table! Why is that? Does it effect on performance ? What are the benefits and use cases ? Should we define foreign keys as primary keys in pivot table in order to make them unique ??

Example of my question: 
[image]

Why should define our many-to-many relationship foreign keys as primary keys ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way to build a junction table, aka bridge table, in a N-M relationship.

Rationale:

- each `order_id` (resp `user_id`) should refer to a record in master table `orders` (resp `users`), so you do want a foreign key on each of these columns to enforce data integrity
- each `(order_id, user_id)` tuple should occur not more than once in the bridge table: this can be enforced by using this columns tuple as a composite primary key, or by setting a `unique` constraint on it.

Of course, it is also possible to define an indenpendent primary key for the junction table (like an auto-incrementend pk), but that is mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks a lot
which has better performance ? using composite primary key or composite unique constraints ?

Comment: @Mr.Apr: I would not expect a performance difference, to me this is mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: More on the optimal schema for many:many mapping table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table